# Java byteArray equivalent in Node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, arrays, image

I have rest API with Node.js and images coming from java application as a byte array.

[This is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnq3s.jpg)

Here is that image converted to a string byte array: 
 [B@c75af72

I want to decode this and check if it is an image and after that upload it on the server.

Also, I want to get images from URLs and convert them to this byte array.

Can anyone help me to encode and decode this kind of stuff?

Comment: Have a look at buffers. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on the fault assumption that `[B@c75af72` somehow describe the content of the byte array. If does not do that, it's simply the result of `toString()` on a `byte[]`. All information it gives is the type (`[B` means `byte[]`) and the identity hash code (which is not related on the *content* of the array at all).

This is not enough information to reproduce the content of the byte-array.

In other words: if that's all you have, then you're out of luck. You must transfer the *content* of your `byte[]` instead of that string.